# Vim: E488 trailing characters error when working with errorformat and quickfix

Tags: vim

I'm trying generate a list of files with `find` and use it in quickfix mode.

I'm executing the following commands:

```
set errorformat=%f
!find . -type f -name "proto_*.c" > tmp.txt
copen tmp.txt
```

but it gives me E488 Trailing characters error.

The file looks just like a normal `find` output, a list of paths starting with `./`, one at a line.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing [`:help :copen`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acopen) with [`:help :cfile`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acfile). The former only takes an optional `[height]` for the quickfix window, the latter takes that `[errorfile]` that you want to pass.

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.

Comment: This question is also on https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/e488-trailing-characters-error-when-working-with-errorformat-and-quickfix, please post your answer there too